# Where can I find the history of type promotion rules except for local variables?

Tags: dart, language-lawyer

I'm a seasoned C/C++/Java/Python developer, but a novice Dart learner. I tested the type promotion with the following code using Dart 3.2.3.

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
  void test() {
  }
}

class C {
  final A a;
  C(this.a);
  void test() {
    // if (a is B) a.test(); // This causes a compile error.
  }
}

void main() {
  A a = B();
  if (a is B) a.test();

  List<A> l = [B()];
  //if (l[0] is B) l[0].test(); // This causes a compile error.

  var c = C(B());
  //if (c.a is B) c.a.test(); // This causes a compile error.
  c.test();
}
```

The language specification [Version 2.13-dev(January 10, 2024)](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf#page=198) says the following for the if statement `if (b) s1 else s2`.

> If b shows that a local variable v has type T, then the type of v is known to
> be T in s1, unless any of the following are true

But a page of the official documentation - [Only local variables can be promoted (before Dart 3.2)](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#property) implies there exists a type promotion rule except for local variables.

Where can I find the history of type promotion rules except for local variables?

Comment: You can reference the changelog: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually new accepted language features can be found [in the language repo](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/tree/main/accepted), and it can take some time before they get integrated into the language specification.

This particular feature is more like a long-term development on the type system, than it's like a new language feature with new syntax and stuff, which is probably why there is no central design document for it in the usual place.

The most relevant documentation is probably this issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2020

The [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#320---2023-11-15) suggested above is probably the best user-aimed documentation.